# Draw a bounding box around character in PDFBOX

Tags: pdfbox

I want to do calculate the bounding box for each character I am drawing to a pdf, for a bunch of different fonts and sizes.  It seems to work differently for different fonts, eg arial mt vs elephant regular.

For example, I have been using the - sign to get a feel for this, in Arial the bottom left is at 65,440 in elephant it is at 7,165 but the elephant is drawn higher and I can't find what this movement comes from.

Most fonts work more like Arial, where the top of the font comes to height/2, but this doesn't work for the elephant font.

What factors need to be included to accurately calculate the bounding box?

```
package com.nexiaem.nemocr.generatepdf;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author bjames
 */
public class DrawBoundngBox {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{

            PDPage thisPage = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(100, 40));
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            document.addPage(thisPage);
            //PDTrueTypeFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, new File("C:\\windows\\fonts\\elephnt.ttf"));
            PDTrueTypeFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, new File("C:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf"));
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, thisPage);

            int thisSize = 10;
            float currentX = 0;                  
            float width = 0;
            String charactersToWrite = "aj";
            char[] characters = charactersToWrite.toCharArray();
            for(char thisChar: characters){
                String thisCharString = Character.toString(thisChar);
                width = (font.getWidthFromFont((int)thisChar) / 1000.0f) * thisSize;
                GeneralPath charPath = font.getPath((int)thisChar);
                Rectangle2D charRect = charPath.getBounds2D();
                float charMinX = thisSize * (float)charRect.getMinX() / 1000.0f;
                float charMaxX = thisSize * (float)charRect.getMaxX() / 1000.0f;
                float charMinY = thisSize * (float)charRect.getMinY() / 1000.0f;
                float charX = thisSize * (float)charRect.getX() / 1000.0f;
                float charY = thisSize * (float)charRect.getY() / 1000.0f;
                Vector displacement = font.getDisplacement((int)thisChar);
                float charWidth = thisSize * (float)charRect.getWidth()/ 1000.0f;
                width = charMaxX - charMinX;

                float height = ((float)charRect.getHeight()/ 1000.0f) * thisSize;
                contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.red);
                contentStream.moveTo(currentX + charMinX/2, 10 + charMinY/2);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charMinX/2, 10 + charMinY/2 + height/2);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charMinX/2 + width/2, 10 + charMinY/2 + height/2);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charMinX/2 + width/2, 10 + charMinY/2);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charMinX/2, 10 + charMinY/2);
                contentStream.stroke();
                contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.green);
                contentStream.moveTo(currentX + charX, 10 + charY);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charX, 10 + charY + height);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charX + width, 10 + charY + height);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charX + width, 10 + charY);    
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + charX, 10 + charY);
                contentStream.stroke();
                contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.yellow);
                contentStream.moveTo(currentX, 10);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX, 10 + height);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + width, 10 + height);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX + width, 10);
                contentStream.lineTo(currentX, 10);
                contentStream.stroke();
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont(font, thisSize);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(currentX, 10);
                currentX = currentX + 30;
                contentStream.showText(thisCharString);
                contentStream.endText();     
            }
            contentStream.close();                  
            document.save("C:\\temp\\DrawBB.pdf");
            document.close();                
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DrawBoundngBox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example from the source code download in the examples subproject?

Comment: Cheers, this nearly achieves what I am after, but without exposing how it is achieved as it basically grabs the rendered text and uses the bounding box of that.  If it almost accurate, except in a couple of cases where the box does not quite enclose the text as the full path of curves are not quite included in the bounding box.

Comment: It gets the bounding box of the paths. Except for type3 fonts where these are not available. The cyan boxes should be accurate except for type3 fonts. There are comments what the colors mean. Your original question is answered in `calculateGlyphBounds()` and is rather complex because each font type is calculated differently. Re `the full path of curves are not quite included in the bounding box` please share the PDF. The only bug I know is of rotated pages with a cropbox.

Comment: The bounding box does work really well, and as descried by Tilman the cyan boxes do a great job in the majority of cases.  How do I attach a file to show where the bounding boxes don't quite do the job?

Comment: upload to a sharehoster and post the link. So e.g. dropbox, google drive or filedropper.com. Don't use a sharehoster that requires registration.